# How to make an enum validation in java?

Tags: java, validation, enums, quarkus

It's a quarkus java project.

The bean that I am trying to validate is:

```
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@RegisterForReflection
public class Launche {

    public static final int VALUE_100 = 100;

    public static final int VALUE_40 = 40;

    public static final int VALUE_10 = 10;

    public static final int VALUE_6 = 6;

    public static final int VALUE_2 = 2;

    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Transaction date", example = "2023-02-21T10:00:00.000Z")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = VALUE_100, message = "size must be between 1 and 100")
    @Schema(description = "Transaction description", example = "Marketplace")
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @PositiveOrZero
    @Schema(format = "BigDecimal", description = "Transaction amount", example = "10.00")
    @Digits(integer = VALUE_10, fraction = VALUE_2)
    private BigDecimal amount;

   
    **@NotNull
    @Schema(format = "enum", description = "Launche type", example = "COMPRA")
    private TypeLaunche type;**
  

    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Score", example = "true")
    private Boolean score;

    @Size(max = VALUE_40, message = "size must be between 1 and 40")
    @Schema(description = "Transaction establishment name", example = "Marketplace")
    private String establishmentName;

    @NotNull
    @Schema(format = "BigDecimal", description = "Real dollar quote of the day", example = "4.50")
    @Digits(integer = VALUE_6, fraction = VALUE_6)
    private BigDecimal dollarQuotation;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return GsonFactory.getInstance().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

The enum class is:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum TypeLaunche {

    COMPRA("COMPRA"),
    ESTORNO("ESTORNO"),
    PAGAMENTO("PAGAMENTO"),
    OUTROS("OUTROS");

    private String value;
}
```

And my validation class is:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EnumTypeValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<EnumTypeValidator, CharSequence> {

    private List<String> acceptedValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final EnumTypeValidator annotation) {
        acceptedValues = Stream.of(annotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final CharSequence value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return acceptedValues.contains(value.toString());
    }

}
```

When I send a **type** different from the enum options my parser sets it as null. Shouldn't the validator throw an error for it being different than the enum options? I set the **type** as a TypeLaunche in my Bean.

I think I don't understand how this validation works.

**Update**

The code where I parse the body of my requisition.
More details: type is an attribute of the class Launche and Launche is an attribute of the class CardInvoice. CardInvoice is the class that I use to parse the body of the requisition. Code below:

```
 private CardInvoice parseCardInvoiceFromMessageBody(final String body) {
        LOGGER.info("Parsing API Gateway Message into CardInvoice object.");
        Gson gson = GsonFactory.getInstance();
        try {
            var obj = gson.fromJson(body, CardInvoice.class);
            LogUtil.setRequestUuid(obj.getUuid());
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid API Gateway Message body.", ex);
            String value = extractValueErrorMessage(String.valueOf(ex));
            JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(body);
            List<String> fields = null;
            if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                fields = findKeys(jsonObject, value);
            }
            throw new InvalidMessageBodyException(String.format("Invalid API Gateway Message body. "
                    + "Parse fields: [%s], value: [%s]", fields, value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you attach parser code also where you passing enum type

Comment: @prasannajoshi just updated with more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public enum TypeLauncher {

    COMPRA("COMPRA"),
    ESTORNO("ESTORNO"),
    PAGAMENTO("PAGAMENTO"),
    OUTROS("OUTROS");

    private final String name;
    
    TypeLaunche(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
}
```

And to set List

```
List<String> acceptedValues = Stream.of(TypeLauncher.values()).map(TypeLauncher::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And than u can compare it